# I want to add query parameters like　?Hoge =false at the end of the URL in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Premise · What you want to realize
I want to add query parameters like　
`?Hoge=false` 
at the end of the URL in laravel 5
Problems occurring · Error messages

If you specify a URL such as MethodNotAllowedHttpException, it will not work.

↑ There is no problem with this
Corresponding source code
**Routes / web.php**

```
 Route::get('/', 'HelloController@index');
```

Hello controller

```
        Public function index($hoge)

        {

        // code

        }
```

PHP, Laravel 5.3

Comment: I think your route like Route::get('/?Hoge={hoge}', 'HelloController@index');

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture the parameter directly, do it like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $hoge = $request->input('hoge');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change route to add param in URL

```
Route::get('/{hoga?}', 'HelloController@index');
```

Question mark indicate it's optional parameter.

Then you can directly catch it to controller's index method.

```
public function index($hoga)
{
    dd($hoga);
}
```

The second way you can Inject Request class into a method like @KelvinC said:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $hoge = $request->input('hoge');
}
```

For second method route should be:

```
Route::get('/{hoga?}', 'HelloController@index');
```